# UICollectionView with overlapping cells and custom insertion and deletion animations

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm working on a custom UICollectionView + Layout where the cells overlap on top of each other. On top of this, I'm implementing custom animations for the addition and removal of items.

Everything's working fine, except the `zIndex` property of the attributes seem to be ignored during insertion/deletion of items.

Proper cells:
[image: Proper cells]

After inserting some cells:
[image: Cells with improper z order]

Here's my implementation for custom insertion/deletion animations. My guess is the problem is somewhere in these methods.

```
override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)

    for updateItem in updateItems {
        switch updateItem.updateAction {
        case .Insert:
            if updateItem.indexPathAfterUpdate == itemIndexPath {
                let translation = collectionView!.bounds.height
                attributes?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, translation)
                break
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    return attributes
}

override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    for updateItem in updateItems {
        switch updateItem.updateAction {
        case .Delete:
            if updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate == itemIndexPath {
                let attributes = layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)
                let translation = collectionView!.bounds.height
                attributes?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, translation)
                return attributes
            }
        case .Move:
            if updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate == itemIndexPath {
                return layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(updateItem.indexPathAfterUpdate!)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    let finalIndex = finalIndexForIndexPath(itemIndexPath)
    let shiftedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: finalIndex, inSection: itemIndexPath.section)

    return layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(shiftedIndexPath)
}

private func finalIndexForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    var newIndex = indexPath.item
    for updateItem in updateItems {
        switch updateItem.updateAction {
        case .Insert:
            if updateItem.indexPathAfterUpdate!.item <= newIndex {
                newIndex += 1
            }
        case .Delete:
            if updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate!.item < newIndex {
                newIndex -= 1
            }
        case .Move:
            if updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate!.item < newIndex {
                newIndex -= 1
            }
            if updateItem.indexPathAfterUpdate!.item <= newIndex {
                newIndex += 1
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return newIndex
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Setting the `zIndex` in the `initialLayoutAttributes...` method to the value it will end up being.
- Making the collection view manually reorder the cells after the animation (which is pretty hacky, and I'd like to avoid this, since it can cause some weird behaviour sometimes).
- Calling `super.initialLayoutAttributes...` etc and modifying the attributes returned from that. The issue with that is it does not handle the other cells shifting when a new one is inserted; instead the cells fade in and out.

A small reproducer of the project can be found on [my GitHub](https://github.com/mpdifran/OverlapCollectionView). Feel free to clone it and play around with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected, it seems the collection view is not properly applying the layout attributes during the animation. Luckily, `UICollectionViewCell` provides a method for you to implement custom layout attributes:

```
override func applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    layer.zPosition = CGFloat(layoutAttributes.zIndex)
}
```

Adding the above code results in the inserted cell appearing at the correct zIndex.

I'll log a radar and comment with the link.

Comment: Hey Mark, I'm in need of this kind of custom overlapping collection view cells. Do you have this custom collection view in Cocoapod library form we can install and use?

Comment: I was thinking more of a standalone Cocoapod package we can just add to podfile, run pod install and start using in our own app rather than having to extract out the related code from an existing project :D I think it would become a very handy library others could benefit from too.

Comment: In your example you manually set the size of each cell at `var preferredSize` is it possible instead reference the collectionViews size? Essentially incorporating some auto layout features into the custom layout.