# coding for custom uicollectionview layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Where/How would I code for this cell layout behavior.

I need each cell to overlap the previous.

Cell 2 centerX is Cell 1 right edge and so forth...

[image]

What method would I override in my custom UICollectionViewLayout?

Comment: I guess you are looking for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393692/uicollectionview-with-overlapping-cells-and-custom-insertion-and-deletion-animat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a custom collectionView layout, override `layoutAttributesForItem` to configure cells layout behavior...

```
var preferredSize: CGSize? = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)


override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

    attributes.size = preferredSize!
//Modifying the centerX property adjust the overlapping effect
    let centerX = (preferredSize?.width)! / 2.0 + CGFloat(indexPath.item) * ((preferredSize?.width)! * 0.5 )
    let centerY = collectionView!.bounds.height / 2.0
    attributes.center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    attributes.zIndex = -(indexPath.item)

    return attributes
}
```